Non HTTP testing via Gatling - is it possible?
I am attempting to write some Gatling scenarios/simulations in Java to performance test a piece of code that I have.
The functionality that I am testing spins up a thread and fires off some SQS messages which are consumed by another application.
Seeing as this is not your typical REST endpoint flow, is it possible to test it via Gatling? I am struggling to find examples of this type of thing, as most Gatling testing seems to be heavily skewed towards endpoint testing.

It's possible to create your own plugin, and Gatling provides the capability to do so. In fact, the http module can even be considered a plugin that comes built-in.
However, developing a plugin is a complex and intricate task.
I've created a plugin for load testing Kafka: https://github.com/Amerousful/gatling-kafka. You can use it as an example and a starting point.

Possible? Yes. Documented? No, as we don't consider our internals stable so we can provide a public API for this.
You can implement your own custom protocol support, several people have been successfully doing so, see https://docs.gatling.io/reference/integrations/third-parties/. You'll have to read the sources then.
You can also reach out to Gatling the company if you're interested in contracting for having this implemented for you.
